# Find common words and push into new array

Tags: javascript

I have Array below and attached output.

> `var
>   arrayData=['cat','mat','tac','hiller','mamaer','llerih','eramam'];
>
> output : [[cat,tac], [mat], [hiller,llerih], [mamaer,erama]];`

Want to extract common letter in an array and store in new array.

i was trying to implement using array.reducer.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to find words made out of the same letters, and group them together in a sub-array, is it? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: yes, absolutely. I have try to implement using Array.reduce function with two for loop but not getting exact result and even that is not efficient. hence looking for better guid.

Comment: ...and may we see your attempt? :)

Comment: give me 30mins, i am re-framing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and a simple loop. The idea is you record each word by creating a "key" from the sum of their character code and length of the word.

Used [Array#Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum the words character codes.

i.e.:

```js
//sum of each letter's character code using reduce
const res1 = "test".split("").reduce((a,c)=>a+c.charCodeAt(), 0);
const res2 = "ttes".split("").reduce((a,c)=>a+c.charCodeAt(), 0);
const l    = "test".length;


const key1 = `${l}_${res1}`;
const key2 = `${l}_${res2}`;

console.log(key1, key2, key1 === key2); //4_448 4_448 true
```

i.e. (without reduce and with for loop):

```js
function sum(word){
  let s = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    s += word[i].charCodeAt();
  }
  return s
}

//sum of each letter's character code using reduce
const res1 = sum("test");
const res2 = sum("ttes");
const l    = "test".length;


const key1 = `${l}_${res1}`;
const key2 = `${l}_${res2}`;

console.log(key1, key2, key1 === key2); //4_448 4_448 true
```

*Recording the length of the word adds an extra level of security incase two different words of lengths different had the same sum*

Full Solution:

```js
const data = ['cat','mat','tac','hiller','mamaer','llerih','eramam'];

const m = new Map();

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  const word = data[i];
  
  const sum = word.split("").reduce((a,c)=>a+c.charCodeAt(), 0);
  const key = `${word.length}_${sum}`;
  m.set(key, [word].concat(m.get(key)||[]));
}

const res = Array.from(m.values());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a different way, I sorted them, grouped them then displayed them by index.

```js
var arrayData=['cat','mat','tac','hiller','mamaer','llerih','eramam'];

var sortedArrayData = arrayData.map(itm => itm.split('').sort((a,b) => a>b).join(''));

var data = {};
sortedArrayData.forEach((itm, indx) => {
  if(!data[itm]) data[itm] = [];
  data[itm].push(indx)
});

var result = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
  return data[key].map(it => arrayData[it])
})


console.log(result)
```

[try it here](https://repl.it/@ZeyadEtman1/BurlyNegligibleBundledsoftware)